# Unable to Override Data in Observer

Tags: attributes, event-observer, catalog

I've been observing this event but it appears that I could not override the value of the array:

Magento event:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_attribute_update_before', array(
    'attributes_data' => &$attrData,
    'product_ids'   => &$productIds,
    'store_id'      => &$storeId
));
```

Here's my code (simplified):

```
public function overrideAttribute(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $attributesData = $observer->getAttributesData();
    $attributesData['index_to_override'] = 'new_value;

    return $this;
}
```

`index_to_override` should have a new value but upon saving, it's still using the array value.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this. I think this should work.

```
public function overrideAttribute(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $attributesData = $observer->getAttributesData();
    $attributesData['index_to_override'] = 'new_value;
    $observer->setAttributesData($attributesData); 
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: That's odd. I've done the same thing, still doesn't work. Digging further.

Comment: print $attrData after Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_attribute_update_before')...